# Потоковая модель в NIO2

Tags: java, многопоточность, nio2

Расскажите пожалуйста, как реализована потоковая модель в NIO2? Правильно ли я понимаю, что при инициализации (или первом установке Callback) создается пул потоков определенного размера и потом все коллбеки (установленные сейчас или позже) могут быть вызваны в произвольном потоке из этого пула?

Если все так, то можно ли как-то влиять на размеры этого пула?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Асинхронный канал можно открыть и с собственным пулом потоков:

```
Executor executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(POOL_SIZE);
AsynchronousChannelGroup group = AsynchronousChannelGroup.withThreadPool(executor);
AsynchronousServerSocketChannel channel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open(group);
```

Если метод `open` вызывается без аргумента, используется пул потоков по умолчанию. Это [CachedThreadPool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newCachedThreadPool--), использующий уже имеющиеся в пуле потоки или создающий новые, если пул уже исчерпан.

Потоки ожидают поступления событий ввода/вывода, извлекают их из очереди, выполняют необходимые действия и вызывают соответствующий метод `CompletionHandler`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В случае пула по умолчанию, методы `CompletionHandler` вызываются в том же потоке, который обрабатывал ввод/вывод. В случае пользовательского пула, ввод/вывод обрабатывается внутренними потоками виртуальной машины, а методы `CompletionHandler` выполняются потоками пользовательского пула.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну, и если операция завершается сразу же, то метод `CompletionHandler` будет вызван непосредственно в потоке инициировавшем операцию.

*Подробнее можно почитать [здесь](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/nio/resources/AsynchronousIo.html). Картинки взяты оттуда же.*